# How do I get all the messages of a specific user on a specific channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So here's the chat (the channel's name is `newchannel` - the channel is created when the player does the command):

```
Bot: Hello, what's your name.
User: BaconSoda479
Bot: When is your birthday
User: 21/06/1999
Bot: Do you like this bot?
User: Yes
```

Now, I'd like to send all the User's messages to a specific channel so that I can create an embed that looks like this when display in the channel:

```
User: BaconSode479
Birthday: 21/06/1999
Opinion: Yes
```

I predict the embed will be something like:

```
`User: ${client.channels.get(newchannel.id).second.message}`
`Birthday: ${client.channels.get(newchannel.id).fourth.message}`
`Opinion: ${client.channels.get(newchannel.id).sixth.message}`
```

I'm trying to make a variable with the string being the `${message.content}` of a specific message in chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the messages of a channel you can use [`TextChannel.fetchMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages). You can then filter those messages to keep only the ones sent by the user with [`Collection.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter). After that, you can use the first three messages to build your embed.
Here's an example:

```
// Assuming newchannel is the TextChannel where the messages are, and that the only user allowed to write in the channel is the one you want to get the data from.

newchannel.fetchMessages().then(collected => {
  const filtered = collected.filter(msg => !msg.author.bot);
  const messages = filtered.first(3);

  const text = `
    User: ${messages[0].content}
    Birthday: ${messages[1].content}
    Opinion: ${messages[2].content}
    `;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fetching the messages later, you can log the results accurately in real time using [`awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages). You should be doing so anyway with the chain of questions.

Place the code below after you've created the new channel (`channel`). The bot will ask the first question and wait for the user's response. It will then be added to the embed and the next question will be asked. After the last question, the embed will be sent and the channel will be deleted.

```js
const questions = [
  { title: 'Name', message: 'Hello! What\'s your name?' },  // You can change these
  { title: 'Birthday', message: 'When\'s your birthday?' }, // messages or add any
  { title: 'Opinion', message: 'Do you like this bot?' }    // questions as you please.
];

const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;

var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor('#ffffff')                                             // Feel free to edit this
  .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL); // embed; only an example.

for (const question of questions) {    
  await channel.send(question.message);
  await channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000 })
    .then(collected => {
      const response = collected.first() ? collected.first().content : '*No Answer*';
      embed.addField(question.title, response.length <= 1024 ? response : `${response.slice(0, 1021)}...`)
    });
}

const responsesTo = message.guild.channels.get('ID'); // Insert the ID to your channel here.
if (!responsesTo) return;

await responsesTo.send(embed); // Could make a webhook for efficiency instead.
await channel.delete();

console.log('Done.');
```

*Note: The code needs to be within an async function.*